# Scroll bars not working though my page overflows in Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I shall give the basic structure of my web page ...... with coloured DIVs for your reference ... The thing is my page overflows and scroll bars are not working even though i added overflow-y:scroll; in my html CSS ..... then i added a JQuery to it too still it does not work quarter of my page is still hidden below the browser .... even when i minimise the browser i the scroll bars are not active ... please help

my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iestyle.css" />
        <title>user logon</title>
        <script>
            $(window).resize(function() {
if($(window).width() <= 1200)
    $("body").css("width","1200px");
else
$("body").css("width","100%");
});

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header" id="header"></div>
<div class="container" id="container">

<div class="left" id="left"> </div>
<div class="center" id="center"></div>
<div class="right" id="right"></div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my css

```
html{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#header {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1323px;
    border: thin ridge #900;

    position: fixed;
    z-index: auto;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
}
#left {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #009;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    border: medium groove #033;

    position: fixed;
    height: 440px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 170px;
    top: 220px;
}
#center{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #39C;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    border: medium groove #033;

    position: fixed;
    height: 440px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 490px;
    top: 220px;
}
#right {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #63C;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    border: medium groove #033;

    position: fixed;
    height: 440px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 810px;
    top: 220px;
}
#container {
    background-color: #6CF;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 440px;
    width: 1310px;
    border: thin groove #F00;
    position: fixed;
    left: 9px;
    top: 214px;
}
```

Can any one help me out with this and i would require this to work on all browsers especially IE 8+ .. thanks in advance

Comment: you dont need to give `overlow` to `HTML`...its by default for the browsers unless u have `hidden` it!

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed is incompatible with scrollbars.
Use `position:absolute`.

here is a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/s593c/

here is the Fixed CSS:

```
html{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#header {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1323px;
    border: thin ridge #900;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: auto;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
}
#left {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #009;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    border: medium groove #033;

    position: absolute;
    height: 440px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 170px;
    top: 220px;
}
#center{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #39C;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    border: medium groove #033;

    position: absolute;
    height: 440px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 490px;
    top: 220px;
}
#right {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #63C;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    border: medium groove #033;

    position: absolute;
    height: 440px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 810px;
    top: 220px;
}
#container {
    background-color: #6CF;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 440px;
    width: 1310px;
    border: thin groove #F00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 214px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other possible way to make it fixed and also allow scroll because when i make it absolute am not getting what i am expecting from my page ... the divs slide over each other.....

Comment: Position fixed aligns your element s strictly to the browser window edges. So It is impossible to scroll these elements. this is the fundamental purpose of position fixed. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp